# Why is a no-args constructor not always inserted by compiler?

Tags: java, constructor

The java compiler automatically inserts a no-args constructor if the programmer provides no constructor. However, if an argumented constructor exists, then the compiler does not insert a no-args constructor.

My question is why? Doesn't it make sense for the compiler to insert a no-args constructor (if it doesn't exist) to EVERY class that is NOT final?

Comment: With what parameter values? Think about it and you have the answer :)

Comment: this is explained in great detail on the internet and the Java documents.

Comment: What if you have final fields that you initialize in your custom constructor and then the compiler inserts a default constructor? Your final fields would not be set.

Comment: If no constructor is specified, a default public constructor with no parameter is being provided. That's it :)

Comment: The compiler should not overrule your intent if you provide ctors wo/ a no-arg constructor.  I think the current arrangement makes perfect sense.  Besides, that ship has sailed.  It's been this way since 1995.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Default Constructor only makes sense when calling it results in a usable state for the class.

If the defaults for the fields do not lead to a usable state (null value for mandatory fields) you don't really want anybody to create it in this particular way.

If you for example have a class which takes a Database connection in it's constructor and stores it in a member, which is then used by several methods in your class. The default constructor would set the member to `null` and all methods would just fail.

If however, it is safe to initiate the class with default values you can always add a no argument constructor. And I think this is the point: If you think a no args constructor is a good idea you have to state this explicitly when another constructor is present. Because it is not always safe to call the "default constructor".

Otherwise you could not really prevent java from creating a default constructor if you don't want one in your design.

Comment: What you said occurred to me. But then, I think, unless you are sure you never want to subclass your class (in which case you should mark it final) you should provide a no-args constructor. For example, you might want to access superclass methods from a subclass..                                                           The only thing I can think of is that the architects of Java think this is bad design- that if you want only to access methods (and not class variables), you should not create a subclass, but rather just import the class.

Comment: @user3516726 When you create a subclass, you still need to invoke the super-constructor with some values.  That makes sense, since any invariants that go for the super class, should also be maintained for any subclass (look up Liskov).

Comment: I believe you give your answer yourself ;) It is rather bad design to use inheritance when you don't really want to instantiate the parent correctly, which in most cases is only possible via the constructor with arguments. If however, it is possible you can always add a no argument constructor (in this case I would argue that a protected one would be the better idea). And I think this is the point: If you think a no args constructor is a good idea you have to state this explicitly when another constructor is present. Because it is not always safe to call the "default constructor".

Answer (score 1):

Because, according to the language specification, if you supply *any* constructor, then the default no-args constructor will not be provided.

Automatic addition of the public no-args constructor is a convenience, if you will.

By specifying any other constructor you are effectively "taking control" and saying to the compiler "hey, please don't add the no-args constructor... if I want one, I'll add it myself".

This is since there might be circumstances where you *don't* want a public no-args constructor (for example, to force object instantiation via a factory class).

Comment: I understand what you say. Please also see my comment to @Frederick.

Comment: Which part of your question is unanswered then? What don't you understand?